# RuntimeError: working outside of request context When request used in first line of method

Tags: python, flask, request

So I have this method that is called with an http.get call.

```
@app.route('/showSQL')
def get_sql():
    spid = request.args['spid']
    instance = request.args['instance']
    user = creds.creds['bh1']['user']
    pw = creds.creds['bh1']['pass']

    print 'calling show sql', spid, instance

    conn = pymssql.connect(instance, user, pw)
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    cmd = 'EXEC master..getSpidSQL ' + str(spid)

    cursor.execute(cmd)
    sql_out = None
    for row in cursor:
        sql_out = row['EventInfo']

    return sql_out
```

I have read that this error comes up with multithreading and alike, but there is nothing complicated here.  The error is being thrown for the first line of this method: 'spid = request.args['spid']'

```
>>> longrunners.get_sql()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/tools/dba/longrunners/longrunners.py", line 48, in get_sql
    spid = request.args['spid']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 20, in _lookup_req_object
raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

I have other methods that are successfully accessing the request object, and have verified that I am in fact sending a param from the browser called 'spid'.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?  I've looked through a bunch of other questions and looked on the web, but found nothing that dealt with this particular situation.

Thanks!

Comment: _always_ show your traceback...

Comment: my apologies! had it ready to copy and paste and I totally forgot.  Just added it, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get_sql` function is a Flask route callback. It expects to be in a request context.

When this function is called with an HTTP request, your `request` will be accessible.

If you want to call it from other contexts, decouple the request and the other parts of your function.

```
@app.route('/showSQL')
def get_sql_callback():
    spid = request.args['spid']
    instance = request.args['instance']
    return get_sql(spid, instance)


def get_sql(spid, instance):
    user = creds.creds['bh1']['user']
    pw = creds.creds['bh1']['pass']

    print 'calling show sql', spid, instance

    conn = pymssql.connect(instance, user, pw)
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    cmd = 'EXEC master..getSpidSQL ' + str(spid)

    cursor.execute(cmd)
    sql_out = None
    for row in cursor:
        sql_out = row['EventInfo']

    return sql_out
```

Now, you can call it from shell or access it as an HTTP request.

Comment: Ohhhhhh! I'm an idiot!  I was getting 500 errors when actually calling this from the app (using an http request) and went to test it in the shell... Which completely negates the use of a request object.  I'm going to implement it in the way you mentioned in order to test what is going wrong.  Thanks!!